# ASIO request-response message "design pattern"?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I'm wondering there exists a technique that allows to implement the following in c++ using `boost::asio`:

The `NetworkService` allows to send messages to connected endpoints, which typically send a response message back which is delegated to an observer (typically a GUI window from which the request is initiated).

(simplified code):

```
void NetworkService::send_message(std::string id, message& msg)
{

    std::shared_ptr<TcpStream> stream = connectionManager_.findStream(id);
    io_service_.post([this, msg, stream]() { stream->deliver(msg);  });
}
```

So, from my MainWindow class, I'm using the service like this:

```
// on button click:
message msg(...);
networkService_->send_message(strEndpointIdentity, msg);
```

And in a event method I'm eventually receiving the response:

```
void MainGui::onMessageReceived(std::shared_ptr<message> msg)
{

}
```

This does work, however, I am wondering if it's possible to implement it in a way that I could send the message, and provide a lambda function as a callback, so that when it receives a response of the corresponding message type, it gets called directly:

("pseudocode"):

```
message request;
networkService_->send_message(endpointAddress, request, 
   [response]{
       txtOutput.text = response.data()
   });
```

Is that even possible?

Additional code:

TcpStream class:

```
void TcpStream::readHeader()
{       
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    asio::async_read(socket_, asio::buffer(read_msg_.header(), message::header_length), [this, self](asio::error_code ec, std::size_t len)
    {
        if (!ec)
        {
            read_msg_.resize();
            readBody();
        }
    });
}

void TcpStream::readBody()
{
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    asio::async_read(socket_, asio::buffer(read_msg_.data(), read_msg_.payload_size()), [this, self](asio::error_code ec, std::size_t)
    {
        if (!ec)
        {
            auto msg = std::make_shared<message>(std::move(read_msg_));             

            if (msg->message_type() == 1)   // initMessage
            {
                this->identity_ =  std::string(read_msg_.data());
                connectionManager_->join(shared_from_this());
            }else{
            // delegate message
                std::for_each(m_listeners.begin(), m_listeners.end(), [&](IStreamListener *l) {l->onMessageReceived(msg); });
            }


            readHeader();  // loop
        }
    });
}

void TcpStream::deliver(const message& msg)
{   
    bool write_in_progress = !write_msgs_.empty();
    write_msgs_.push_back(msg);
    if (!write_in_progress)     
        write();        
}

void TcpStream::write()
{
    auto self(shared_from_this());

    asio::async_write(socket_, asio::buffer(write_msgs_.front().header(),message::header_length),[this, self](asio::error_code ec, std::size_t)
    {
        if (!ec)
        {
            asio::async_write(socket_, asio::buffer(write_msgs_.front().data(), write_msgs_.front().payload_size()),
                [this, self](asio::error_code ec, std::size_t)
            {
                if (!ec)
                {
                    write_msgs_.pop_front();
                    if (!write_msgs_.empty())
                    {
                        write();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Is there anything wrong with just [accepting a `std::function`](https://gist.github.com/SeanCline/b99e468918e30c8b8240ce2280e8c822) in `send_message` and calling it when done? A more elegant solution might be to return a `future` from `send_message` and [use it for continuations](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures.then). Unfortunately, support for future continuations is experimental Boost.

Comment: Are you interested in the context where `networkService_->sendMessage` is to be suspended until the response handler is invoked? I.e., a line after `networkService_->sendMessage` wouldn't be executed until the response handler callback is called?  If so, does seem like you want a future like @SeanCline said but coroutines could also work.

Comment: Aw god, I always avoided futures/promises etc. as I never understood how to use them but it could be what I'm looking for. Usually, there will not be lines after the sendMessage, as it will only continue as readBody() delegated received a response to that request for that exact socket (TcpStream). So I would probably have to keep a set of futures and "resolve" the promise/future inside the  TcpStream::readBody() function when a response has been received, right? Any idea if that can be done with std::future already, so I wouldn't need the overhead of boost:: (I'm using asio standalone)